# Scraping paths from a Gruntfile

Tags: regex, vimscript, grunt.js

As a part of my [Tabv](https://github.com/Kazark/vim-tabv) Vim plugin (which at this stage is nothing more than a pitiful rag-tag assortment of half-baked hacks), I have a function which attempts to guess the directory paths for main source and unit tests. The first working version of this function is ([full source](https://github.com/Kazark/vim-tabv/blob/cb0f0361feb5f1fd06f6733005c2500b71af40a1/plugin/tabv.vim)):

```
let g:tabv_grunt_file_path='Gruntfile.js'

function s:GuessPathsFromGruntfile()
    execute "sview " . g:tabv_grunt_file_path
    global/^\_s*['"].*\*\.spec\.js['"]\_s*[,\]]\_s*/y a
    let l:matches = matchlist(getreg('a'), '[''"]\(.*\)/\*\.spec\.js[''"]')
    if len(l:matches) > 1
        let g:tabv_javascript_unittest_directory = l:matches[1]
    endif
    global/^\_s*['"].*\*\.js['"]\_s*[,\]]\_s*/y a
    let l:matches = matchlist(getreg('a'), '[''"]\(.*\)/\*\.js[''"]')
    if len(l:matches) > 1
        let g:tabv_javascript_source_directory = l:matches[1]
    endif
    close
endfunction
```

Also relevant, from the same script, and above the function shown:

```
let g:tabv_javascript_source_directory="src"
let g:tabv_javascript_source_extension=".js"
let g:tabv_javascript_unittest_directory="unittests"
let g:tabv_javascript_unittest_extension=".spec.js"
```

Now, the algorithm needs some help, but that's not what I'm worried about at the moment. (I try to build out this plugin on an as-needed basis, rather than going for the gold, so to speak.) What I do not like is:

- The code duplication

  - The fact that the first and second parts of the function are similar.
  - The fact that I am not using the global variables for the file extensions in the regular expression.
- The fact that I am actually visually opening and closing the Gruntfile.
- The `execute` statement

What else do you see wrong here, and how could I do better? What can I do to correct the problems mentioned above?

Comment: In retrospect I think the whole approach is necessarily a hack.